# How to get sync return from ExecuteScript in WebView2

Tags: .net, winforms, webview

Just trying out the Winforms WebView2 from here: https://github.com/michael-russin/webview2-control

Trying to work out how to get use [ExecuteScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2/reference/iwebview2webview#executescript) synchronouly. Blocking the thread in any way, prevents the script from running.

```
Friend Function ExecuteSync(Script As String) As String
    ExecuteScript(Script, Sub(e) ExecuteSync = e.ResultAsJson)
End Function
```

Any help is appreciated as I can't find any examples of how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about Michael's version of the webview2 wrapper, but if you use the official Microsoft One:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/webview2-api-reference

Which has much of the same method and property names as Michael's version.

Then you can get a sync call to any object you implement from your JavaScript code simply by using the sync object that can be found in the host objects array using the following code:

```
var mynum = chrome.webview.hostObjects.sample.myMethod().sync();
```

In C# (Sorry I don't know the VB equivalent) you would implement "myMethod" in a class as follows:

```
using Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EdgeWebView2Test.MyClasses
{
  [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public class MyJavaScriptApiClass
  {
    public int MyMethod()
    {
      return 10;
    }
  }
}
```